# Automator loop to run same workflow on several subfolders in same directory

Tags: loops, applescript, automator

I have a workflow to rename a specific file with the name of the parent folder.
In this directory, there might be several folders where it should be run. 
I can't find the right way to build a loop that would complete all instructions on the first subfolder before continuing to the next one  ... and so on. With my loop, the workflow reads all the subfolders and mixes all the items, gets stuck because it provides several names when only one is required to rename the file ;  I want it to complete all work on one subfolder at the time before reading and proceeding to the following one.
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

I added  Dispense Items Incrementally after the finder finds the items, and a loop at the end, but I run into another problem: the workflow finds the subfolder and the file to rename, Applescript fetches the info to paste later on, but after that, Automator cannot find the file anymore to rename it. The link seems to be lost. What did I miss ? (When run without the loop on a single subfolder, everything works fine) Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have your script get the folders first, then loop them. In the loop of the folder, you can get the contents of it and then work accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your time.